# delete all directories except one

Tags: shell, posix

So using the shell, and having a directory:

```
./parent
./parent/one
./parent/two
./parent/three
./parent/four
```

i want to do something like `rm -rf parent/*` in one command, but keeping one directory, for example 'four', so the end result would be

```
./parent
./parent/four
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

With `bash` you can do this with the `extglob` option of `shopt`.

```
shopt -s extglob
cd parent
rm -rf !(four)
```

With a posix shell I think you get to use a loop to do this

```
for dir in ./parent/*; do
    [ "$dir" = "four" ] && continue
    rm -rf "$dir"
done
```

or use an array to run `rm` only once (but it requires arrays or using `"$@"`)

```
arr=()
for dir in ./parent/*; do
    [ "$dir" = "four" ] && continue
    arr+=("$dir")
done
rm -rf "${arr[@]}"
```

or

```
for dir in ./parent/*; do
    [ "$dir" = "four" ] && continue
    set -- "$@" "$dir"
done
rm -rf "$@"
```

or you get to use `find`

```
find ./parent -mindepth 1 -name four -prune -o -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

or (with `find` that has `-exec +` to save on some `rm` executions)

```
find ./parent -mindepth 1 -name four -prune -o -exec rm -rf {} +
```

Oh, or assuming the list of directories isn't too large and unwieldy I suppose you could always use

```
rm -rf parent/*<ctrl-x>*
```

then delete the `parent/four` entry from the command line and hit <kbd>enter</kbd> where `<ctrl-x>*` is readline's default binding for `glob-expand-word`.

Comment: Excellent answer. I normally just `mv` the directory and delete everything else. ;) +1

Comment: @erip Heh, yeah that's certainly a much easier route in many cases. Though `extglob` is almost as simple.

Comment: Careful!  That `find` as written will also match `./parent` !

Comment: Perfect! went with find ./parent -mindepth 1 -name four -prune -o -exec rm -rf {} +

Comment: This is just the correct form of that find example from OP `find ./ -mindepth 1 -name four -prune -o -exec rm -rf {} \;`

Comment: Can you explain **why** or **how** the Ctrl-X works? A documentation link would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: The `-mindepth 1` parameter ensures that the `find` command will not delete the `./parent` folder.

Answer (score 20):

Easiest and practical way in my opinion is to move the exception to parent folder, delete everthing move it back

```
mv exceptionFolder ..
rm -rf *
mv ../exceptionFolder .
```

Edit: If there is no parent directory

```
mkdir todelete
mv * todelete/
mv todelete/exceptionFolder .
rm -rf todelete
```

Answer (score 11):

Another way would be to

```sh
rm -r $(ls -A | grep -v important_folder)
```

`ls -A` lists all files and folders (other than . and ..).

`grep -v expression` removes anything matching the grep expression from the list.

Comment: You can also add the `-E` flag to grep to use capture groups and `|` and then you can easily add more folders: `grep -vE "(file1)|(file2)"` finds everything except those two files.

Comment: You can also add the `-x` flag to grep to match full lines (in case any other folders include the name of the folder to save)

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with `find`

```
 find . -maxdepth 1 ! -name foldder_name -type d -not -path '.' -exec rm -rf {} +
```

`find` - Its command search files/directories

`-maxdepth 1` - Do not find for `foldder_name` subcategories

`. ! -name foldder_name` - It means search in current directory `.` and do not fide this file with his actual name: `! -name foldder_name`

`-type d` - find only directories

`-not -path '.'` - do not found hidden folders

`-exec rm -rf {} +` - remove all found data