# How to create a daemonset to manage (create or remove or check if exists then do nothing) a list of directories under "/var/log" parent directory

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, daemonset

The directories to be created/managed should be dynamic and be read from `values.yaml` file of the helm release.

The Daemonset definition which I could think of is mentioned below:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: create-directory
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: create-directory
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: create-directory
    spec:
      # use default service-account with scc role-binding
      ServiceAccountName: default
      containers:
      - name: create-directory
        image: "{{ .Values.container.image }}"
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        command: ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
        args:
          - |
            {{- range .Values.directories }}

            dir_path="/var/log/at/{{ . }}"
            echo $dir_path

            # Check if the directory exists
            if [ -d "$dir_path" ]; then
              echo "Directory $dir_path already exists."
            else
              # Create the directory
              mkdir -p "$dir_path" && echo "Directory $dir_path created."
            fi

            {{- end }}
            
            while true; do
              sleep 100000;
            done
        # run the container as root
        securityContext:
          runAsUser: 0
        volumeMounts:
          - name: at-volume
            mountPath: /var/log/at
      volumes:
        - name: at-volume
          hostPath:
            path: /var/log/at
```

where the `values.yaml` file for the helm chart looks like below:

```yaml
container:
  image: registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/toolbox:8.5
directories:
  - directory1
  - directory2
```

I need the guidance on the below mentioned:

1. Is my approach of using the `sleep` to keep the pod alive and stop it from being rescheduling once the directory check script is executed, is correct or does the community recommend something else?
2. How can I remove directories once they are removed from the `values.yaml` directories list?

**UPDATE**
For (1) I could find a solution: "[Run-once Kubernetes DaemonSet pods](https://haim.dev/posts/2022-01-01-run-once-kubernetes-daemonset-pods/)"

Comment: `{{- range .Values.directories }}` runs even when the `.Values.directories` is empty list which is weird. I tried using the if/else approach and length eq 0 both seems to be having no effect on the range. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

For the question #2, you can try something:

```
rm -rf !({{ .Values.directories | join "|" }})
```

This will remove all the directories except the ones listed. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34057047/delete-all-directories-except-one) for more examples.

Comment: I think of using the below approach considering the `.Values.directories` list only contains the sub-directory names and not the full path.


for existing_dir in /var/log/at/*; do
  dir=$(basename "$existing_dir")
  if ! grep -q "$dir" <<< "{{ .Values.directories }}"; then
    rm -rf "$existing_dir"
    echo "Directory $existing_dir removed."
  fi
done

Comment: I forgot to mention it, before the above command, you need to move the parent folder with `cd /var/log/at`. Anyway, your solution works too.